# Google breakpad build error

Tags: android, c++, google-breakpad

Building google breakpad for android but getting build errors.
don't know how to fix them.
 code checkout from: [code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/breakpad/breakpad/+/master)

and building as ndk build.  the checkout code did not have lss folder.

```
google-breakpad/android/google_breakpad/../../src/google_breakpad/common/breakpad_types.h:45:2: error: #error "inttypes.h has already been included before this header file, but "
 #error "inttypes.h has already been included before this header file, but "
  ^
jni/../google-breakpad/android/google_breakpad/../../src/google_breakpad/common/breakpad_types.h:46:2: error: #error "without __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS defined."
 #error "without __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS defined."
/google-breakpad/android/google_breakpad/../../src/common/memory.h:51:51: fatal error: third_party/lss/linux_syscall_support.h: No such file or directory
 #include "third_party/lss/linux_syscall_support.h"
```

Answer (score 21):

Command line is:

```
cd breakpad
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/linux-syscall-support src/third_party/lss
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, and wasted a lot of times.

To solve this, I tried to do this:

1. "git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/linux-syscall-support"
2. copy linux_syscall_support.h from "git\linux-syscall-support" to "android_breakpad\src\third_party\lss"

hope to help everyone.

Comment: Thanks you, now I can use the tools